# PSNR decreases while denoising

Tags: noise, opencv, denoising

I currently am trying to portray PSNR's ability to measure noise in an image. The PSNR is said to be high (around 40 dB) if there is a low amount of noise in the 2D signal.

In my experiment I have fairly noisy image (artificially added) and through 6 iterations I add more and more denoising strength with `fastNlMeansDenoisingColored` from `opencv`.

[image: PSNR and MSE over 6 steps of applying denoising]

Obviously we can see that `fastNlMeansDenoisingColored` smoothes out the image more and more but is that the actual reason why the PSNR decreases?

I'm trying to calculate the PSNR by implementing it myself:

```py
def get_psnr(original_image, denoised_image, R=255):
    assert original_image.dtype == denoised_image.dtype

    mse = np.mean((original_image.astype(np.float32) - denoised_image.astype(np.float32)) ** 2)
    if mse == 0:
        return np.inf
    
    psnr = 20 * np.log10(R / np.sqrt(mse))
    return psnr
```

During all the steps I add more denoising effect but in every step I measure the PSNR of the original input image and the denoised image. The `MAX_VALUE` or `R` in my case always stays 255 as I don't normalize or standardize my image's pixel values.

Comment: I know what *"SNR"* means.  What does the *"P"* stand for?

Comment: It's the Peak Signal-To-Noise Ratio, the SNR is dependent on the ratio of the signal power in respect to the noise power while the PSNR is dependent on the ratio of the maximum possible signal power in respect to the MSE of the signal power.

Comment: It's a good thing to spell that out.